# Intersect plot and parametric region

Tags: plotting, regions

I have a vector plot and a region plot on the same scale and I wish to join them like when using Show[ , ]. Now, the vector plot has part outside the region that I would like to delete. Any idea how to do it ? Thanks !

Here repectively the region and vector plots:

[image][image]

The superimposition

[image]

So I would like to remove the segments of the lines lying outside the shaded area.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Does something like `StreamPlot[{x^2,y},Element[{x,y},ImplicitRegion[2x^3+y^2<1,{x,y}]],StreamScale->None]` work?

Comment: @cvgmt I'm essentially using ListStreamPlot[list, StreamScale -> None, StreamColorFunction -> None] with some list (the result of a numerical integration of a PDE) and RegionPlot[W]  for some parametric region W.

Comment: @Adam It works, but I was looking for some solution after obtaining both plots. Getting each one of them takes considerable machine time so I did not want to run it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `RegionFunction` you can restrict the `ListStreamPlot` to a parametric region. I will have to create some data first.

```
ℛ = 
  ParametricRegion[{{s, (1 + t) s^2 - t}, -1 <= s <= 1 && 
     0 <= t <= 1}, {s, t}];
```

[image]

```
data = Table[{{x, y}, {y, x - y}}, {x, -1.5, 1.5, 0.2}, {y, -2, 2, 
    0.2}];
ListStreamPlot[data
 , AspectRatio -> Automatic
 ]
```

[image]

You can use `RegionFunction` like this:

```
ListStreamPlot[data
 , RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y}, RegionMember[ℛ, {x, y}]]
 , AspectRatio -> Automatic
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent !!! Thank you so much.

Comment: You are most welcome. Thanks for the accept.